# R help, shell prompt changed and none of the commands work

Tags: r

This question is related to R, I have written   >help('[[") instead of >help("[[") and the shell prompt changed from > to + and none of my commands work. How do i get back to the default shell prompt

Comment: Type `'''` in console and press Enter

Comment: If you made such a mistake and R is waiting for further input, just press the "Esc" key.

Answer (score 0):

press Escape key to get out of the + sign